# Impala partition queries running slow

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

So I was trying to partition my Impala table with the column 'file' which has 1500 distinct records. That means 1500 partitions. I first run a query like this to return the partition queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  concat('insert into partitioned_table partition (year=',
    cast(year as string),', month=',cast(month as string),
    ') select c1, c2, c3 from raw_data where year=',
    cast(year as string),' and month=',cast(month as string),';') AS command
  FROM raw_data;
```

Then I got 1500 queries to run.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byyVy.png)

Now there's one problem: Since each query might take 3 minutes to finish. 1500 queries could take several days. Which is a really long time. To save the time, I have already done some tuning: using COMPUTE STATS to get statics, convert table to Parquet. MY question is, Is there a way that can speed up this process? Like max up the executors just like Hive can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dynamic partitioning](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_partitioning.html#partition_static_dynamic)

```
insert into partitioned_table partition (year,month) 
select c1, c2, c3, year, month
from raw_data
```

---

Demo

```
create table t (i int) partitioned by (year string,month string);

insert into t partition (year,month) values
    ( 1,'2015','02')
   ,( 2,'2017','01')
   ,( 3,'2016','02')
   ,( 4,'2013','09')
   ,( 5,'2015','07')
   ,( 6,'2012','03')
   ,( 7,'2012','12')
   ,( 8,'2017','12')
   ,( 9,'2015','11')
   ,(10,'2015','02') 
;   

select * from t order by year,month,i;
```

---

```
+----+------+-------+
| i  | year | month |
+----+------+-------+
| 6  | 2012 | 03    |
| 7  | 2012 | 12    |
| 4  | 2013 | 09    |
| 1  | 2015 | 02    |
| 10 | 2015 | 02    |
| 5  | 2015 | 07    |
| 9  | 2015 | 11    |
| 3  | 2016 | 02    |
| 2  | 2017 | 01    |
| 8  | 2017 | 12    |
+----+------+-------+
```

---

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/hive/warehouse/t;
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2012
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2012/month=03
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2012/month=03/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_1891304442_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2012/month=12
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2012/month=12/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_798564417_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2013
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2013/month=09
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2013/month=09/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_432428758_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2015
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2015/month=02
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          5 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2015/month=02/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_768620898_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2015/month=07
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2015/month=07/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_2029099237_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2015/month=11
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2015/month=11/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_974618320_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2016
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2016/month=02
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2016/month=02/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_502842645_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2017
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2017/month=01
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2017/month=01/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_2014291428_data.0.
drwxr-xr-x   - impala supergroup          0 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2017/month=12
-rw-r--r--   1 impala supergroup          2 2017-02-07 13:45 /user/hive/warehouse/t/year=2017/month=12/174c30c4e1edc236-b57504ce4afd76a2_1693475255_data.0.
```

Comment: Hi Dudu, After I run this query for a while, it throws an exception: **Could not connect to vn1.localdomain:21050 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to vn1.localdomain:21050',)** .Here is the screen shot: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zBU9nhCbhYNlY1Y0kxUmtCbEU)  My guess is that impala may run out of memory due to multiple concurrent read/write. How do you solve that? Thanks

Comment: Hi Aaron. It is problematic to tackle it without a log

Comment: You can try a naive solution - run the insert with a where clause taking only a part of the data.

Comment: P.s. or simply do it in Hive

Comment: I successfully partitioned it by separating with a where clause and now it works fine. Thank you for the help!